# What does it mean to say $K$-theory satisfy Mayer–Vietoris sequence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, k-theory, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

I saw the statement "a $K$-theory is expected to satisfy Mayer–Vietoris property and Bott Periodicity" somewhere and I am trying to understand what it means.

What does it mean to say a $K$-theory satisfies Mayer–Vietoris property/Bott Periodicity?

Comment: K-theory is a generalized cohomology theory which means it satisfies the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms, and from these axioms you can derive the [Mayer-Vietoris sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence). [Bott Periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem) is something particular to K-theory, and there are different statement for real and complex (and Real) K-theories. The simplest way of stating it for complex K-theory is "$K^n(*)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ if $n$ is even, and $0$ otherwise" but it's much deeper than that.

Comment: when people say "*a* K-theory" it can often mean many things (there's topological K-theories and K-theories for $C^*$ algebras and algebraic K-theories etc.) so what exactly is meant by "Mayer-Vietoris/Bott Periodicity" could depend on the context.

Comment: for example, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404988900874) talks about Mayer-Vietoris sequences in Algebraic K-theory, and points out that they don't always exist. I also found [a paper](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~dan/KtheoryHandbook-for-authors-only/1-4.pdf) which discusses Bott periodicity in the context of several K-theories, including topological and algebraic

Comment: @William Thanks.. I will read that

Comment: In the case of topological K-theory, the statement of Bott periodicity and Mayer-Vietoris can be found at p34 Theorem 3.3.8. and p36 section 3.4 of https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~or257/teaching/notes/Kthy.pdf